# WinRT (Metro App) - Trying to create GregorianCalendar, JulianCalendar, HebrewCalendar - Name not found

Tags: c#, calendar, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Using Visual Studio 2012 to write a Metro App.  I am trying to port some of my .NET 2.0 code up.  I need to create instances of certain calendars to do date conversions of some scanned data.

Roughly, I am simply doing this:

```
using System.Globalization;

Calendar cal = null;

cal = new GregorianCalendar;

....

cal.GetDaysInMonth(year, month);
```

However, the calendar objects seem unavailable.  I have spent the better part of 8 hours looking for a workaround in System.Globalization as well as Windows.Globalization and found thing.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you *only* need `GetDaysInMonth`?

Comment: Use the Windows.Globalization.Calendar class.  ChangeCalendarSystem() to pick another calender.  Call SetDateTime().  The NumberOfDaysInThisMonth property returns what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic.  Thank you for the clues.  This actually lead into something that works pretty well.

First:
using Windows.Globalization;

Then:
Calendar cal = new Calendar;

Later:
cal.ChangeCalendarSystem(CalenderIdentifiers.Gregorian); // (or any of the others, Julian, Hebrew,

Then later on:
scratchDateTime = new DateTime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0); // set year month and day with a don't matter time
cal.SetDateTime(scratchDateTime);
int daysInMonth = cal.NumberOfDaysInThisMonth();

Comment: You can also set the year, month, day directly on the cal. Be sure to do it in that order though or you may have coercion of the date that takes place to keep it valid.